# jQuery/Ajax/PHP - cant seem to figure out what is wrong

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modx

For some reason this ajax call I'm working on is returning the error state in the console log... I can't seem to figure out why, everything looks correct to me!

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.load-more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('Starting AJAX');

        var $this = $(this);

        var load   = $this.data('current-page') + 1;

        var parent = $this.data('parent');

        var properties = {
            snippet: 'infiniteScroll',
               limit: 3,
               offset: 0,
               parents: 22,
               depth: 999,
               sortby: 'publishedon',
               showHidden: 1,
               debug: 1,
               tpl: 'infiniteHomePageTpl',
               };

          $this.data('current-page', load);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.processor",
            data: properties,
            cache: false,
               dataType: "json",

            success: function(response) {

                if(response.status == 'success'){

                    console.log('Success');

                }else if(response.status == 'error'){

                    console.log('data error');

                }else{

                    console.log('some other error');

                }

              },

              error: function(response){

                 console.log('an error has occurred' + response);

              },

        }); // ajax
    });

});// document ready
```

The processor being called:

```
<?php

// $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'Running ajax.processor, snippet = '.$_POST['snippet'].' formdata = '. print_r($_POST, TRUE));

$output = $modx->runSnippet($_POST['snippet'],array(
   'snippet' => $_POST['snippet'],
   'data' => $_POST
));

// set the header for the ajax call

$output =  json_encode($output);

header('Content-type: application/json');

$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'Should be json = '.$output);

echo $output;
```

The code that the processor execute:

```
<?php

    //$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Running infinitescroll snippet' . print_r($scriptProperties, TRUE));

    $output = array(
      'status' => 'success',
      'msg' => 'a message of some type',
      'whatever' => 'this is some data',
    );

    return $output;
```

The logging line in the processor will output json to the log:

```
Should be json = {"status":"success","msg":"a message of some type","whatever":"this is some data"}
```

so my javascript ~should~ be getting json back, but its not hitting the success condition, all I get in the console log is:

```
an error has occurred[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try JSON.stringify() on the error response

Comment: Make sure your PHP is returning a JSON string also. It will fail every time if it's not, since it's expecting a json return.

Comment: The 2nd last line of my processor is logging json to my system log before it echos it back to the javascript.  So, yes, I think it is, but is there a way to test if the response is actually json?

Comment: I prefer to do that sort of stuff in Firefox. The dev tools are basic, but have excellent request call tools. I'd suggest looking into that, and looking at the return coming from the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to json_encode the php array, as Kaleb has already commented. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

So your code should be:

```
//$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Running infinitescroll snippet' . print_r($scriptProperties, TRUE));

$output = array(
  'status' => 'success',
  'msg' => 'a message of some type',
  'whatever' => 'this is some data',
);

$json = json_encode($output);

return $json;
```

I would also suggest that you use Firebug to monitor your javascript rather than logging console messages: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: the array is encoded in the processor before it is returned to the javascript.

Comment: Sorry, Sean, did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an HTTP client such as [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) (or even cURL) to mock your AJAX call. This makes it easy to inspect the headers and contents of response.

Also, when the error handler is called the first argument will always be an XHR object. If you do `console.log(response);` (without the string casting) you should be able to inspect its contents. What might be of more use for you though are the other two parameters:

> error
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String
>   errorThrown )

More info is in [the jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a json content type header **and** to encode the output:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

    //$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Running infinitescroll snippet' . print_r($scriptProperties, TRUE));
    $output = array(
      'status' => 'success',
      'msg' => 'a message of some type',
      'whatever' => 'this is some data',
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
```

And if you wanted to know why this is happening, you can expect the `errorThrown` by using `$.ajax.fail()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax.php",
    data: properties,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",

success: function(response) {
//your code
},

error: function(response){
//your code 
},

}).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: json header is in the processor

Comment: Also note I'm using `echo`, not `return`. You need to use `echo` or the JSON won't be displayed by your `/ajax.processor` endpoint.

Comment: the code runuses return back to the processor, but the processor is echoing the return data.  now at least I'm getting : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"} as an error.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly define the content type for it to work. It's recommended to do so, but not a requirement.

Comment: @SeanKimball try temporarily changing your `dataType` to 'html' as you're not getting JSON back from the processor for some reason.

Comment: It's probably sending the HTML response to your success function now, because you told it to expect HTML. Once you figuire out the problem, switch it back to JSON.